# How to remove this json node this json via xslt mapping

Tags: json, xslt

How to remove {"root": and "" this json via xslt mapping

```json
{
   "root": [
      {
         "TPDName": "160 TPD ",
         "LineName": "J20",
         "JobName": "120 ML HIMALAYA [PLAIN] -DS120",
         "PONumber": "000009000162",
         "OLDPONumber": "000001003901",
         "FGCode": "A3W0254QNPQ000001X",
         "OfferedDate": "2023-12-06T11:38:33.00Z",
         "HourlyProductionInspectionLotNumber": "040000013878",
         "PaletteQuantities": {
            "PaletteNumber": 285,
            "Quantity": "10 ",
            "HUNumber": 1000102548
         },
         "ProductCode": "A3W0254QNPQ000001X"
      },
      ""
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0 you can do

```
$json?root?*1
```